How to add a second PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer without losing Spring Boot's default property resolution?
I am creating a Spring Boot application. I want to use Spring Boot's default mechanism for Spring's property resolution.
I also need to embed an already existing custom Spring library. This library already includes a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.
However, as soon as I add this already existing PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, Spring's default mechanism for property resolution gets disabled. That is because Spring's auto-configuration is then disabled.
How can I keep Spring Boot's default property resolution, and add a second PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer?

If we want to keep Spring Boot's default property resolution while adding a second PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, we can create a configuration class to instantiate Bean of type PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean.
@Configuration
public class CustomPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setEnvironment(environment);
        return configurer;
    }
}

In addition we MUST NOT

add @EnableAutoConfiguration(false)
or any other configuration that disables auto-configuration.

Let me know if this works for you.
